# How to kill a process on Ctrl+C event in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to override the <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> event by using the [ctrlc](https://github.com/Detegr/rust-ctrlc) package. I want to kill a child process on the event. I'm currently doing this.

```rust
let mut child = Command::new(shell)
    .arg(option)
    .arg(script)
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();

ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
    println!("Received Ctrl+C!");
    child.kill().expect("Couldn't kill the process!");
})
.expect("Error setting interrupt handler!");

child.wait().unwrap();
```

But I'm having the error `cannot borrow child as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a Fn closure`. What is the meaning of the error, and how can I solve this?

Comment: I think you need to use some rc combine with some refcell

Answer (score 0):

[`set_handler`](https://docs.rs/ctrlc/3.1.4/ctrlc/fn.set_handler.html) starts "a new dedicated signal handling thread".

It seems that `set_handler` expects `Fn`, which - in contrast to `FnMut` - cannot be mutated. As it cannot mutate, it cannot mutate the captured `child`.

You can try defining `child` within the closure and communicate to the outer thread.

You could try to establish communication between the threads (e.g. using [`mpsc::channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html)) instead of `wait`ing for `child` in the main thread. You could try to retrieve [stdout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stdout)/[stderr](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stderr) instead of `wait`ing.

Comment: I don't think `wait` is the problem, as even if I removed the last line, the `cannot borrow child as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a Fn closure` error is still there with the `kill` call.